# Google Appscript change date format and currency

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, google-docs, google-apps

did you know how to change the date format from DD/MM/YYYY to YYYY/MM/DD and currency format ?
because I already did change the date format to YYYY/MM/DD and currency to  ₩1,000 in spreadsheet, but after running the AppScript and generate to doc, the data won't change, it still same as default DD/MM/YYYY and for the currency just show ordinary number (ex : 1250000 it should be like this  ₩1,250,000)

this case I make Auto Fill Google Doc Template from Google Sheets Data Using Google Apps Script.

```
const friendlyDate = new Date(row[7]).toLocaleDateString();
```

I expecting format YYYY/MM/DD and the currency format.

Comment: I think it depends of the timezone settings you have in your appsscript.json file - check [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/manifest)

Comment: See also [here](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates#:~:text=To%20make%20sure%20your%20date,%3Amm%3Ass%20Z%20format.), [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/62914/279108) and [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/100644/279108).